# How to Redirect User to Another URL Depending on the URL He Came From

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, conditional-statements

Can a javascript code that runs when a page loads or equivalent solution detect which pior URL the user came from, and if the user came from a certain url then the javascript would forward the user to another defined url?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get url of the previous page: `document.referrer`